# How is a C# dictionary implemented? (C++)

Tags: c#, c++, dictionary

Hi I'm using C++ to create a C# like dictionary object. I use a similar system of garbage collected ref objects for everything which are moved around in memory as the program runs.  I've started off by implementing the dictionary aa a pretty standard hash table which is fine and I have this type of layout:

```
header + hash table -> storage -> element 0 -> object x
                                  element 1 -> object y
                                  element ... -> object ...

'+': In same allocation 
'->': Indirect pointer ie different allocation
```

So 'header' contains just the table size. 'Hash table' is an array of integer offsets into the storage area.

The storage is implemented as a C# list ie an indirect pointer (ref object) to a self sizing array ie like a C++ vector.

Each element (`Dictionary::Element`) in the storage holds an id, an indirect pointer (ref object) to the actual object and an integer offset to the next element.

```
// C++ like pseudo code:
template< typename _Type_, typename _HashType_ = int >
class Dictionary
{
private:

   class Element
   {
       _HashType_ m_id;
       _Type_     m_object;   // Ref object ie indirect pointer to actual object
       int        m_next;     // Next element
   }

   int            m_tablesize; // Power of 2
   int*           m_table;     // Pointer here but in reality just a continuous block                      
                               // of memory after m_tablesize;
   List<Element>  m_storage;      // Like a C++ vector
}
```

So my question is C#'s dictionary only allows one object at a time for any one hash.

Is there a simpler approach than the above implementation?

For example `Dictonary::Add(_HashType_ id, _Type_ object)` in the above implementation will bitwise AND the hash with the table size to get an index into the hash table then allocate an element with the id and object passed in and then it will add (push back) that element to the list (m_storage) of elements and fix up the linked list of elements:

```
template < typename _Type_, typename _HashType_ >
inline bool Dictionary< _Type_, _HashType_ >::Add( _HashType_ id, _Type_ element )
{
    Element element = Element::New( id, object );
    m_storage->Add( element );

    // PushBack here fixes up the offset of the element in the storage array stored in 
    // the hash table (zero elements for this id) or the next pointer in the element 
    // (one or more elements exist for this id)
    return PushBack( element );
}
```

Being a bit more explicit: is there a way to just have a header and hash table of objects ie:

```
header + hash table -> object x
                       object y
                       ...
```

I ask this because C# imposes a one item limit on each hash when the more complex implementation above has no such limitations really except Remove would need to pass in both the id and the object and possibly you might want PushFront and PushBack instead of Add.

Thanks in advance and please don't ask why I'm doing this seemingly crazy thing just humor me! :)

Comment: [`std::unordered_map<Key,Value>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) *whistles*

Comment: What makes you think you're limited to one item per hash?

Comment: @xeo std::unordered_map doesn't work in an environment where the underlying memory is moved around...

Comment: @RowlandShaw It says in the MSDN documentation: 'However, if the specified key already exists in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, setting the Item property overwrites the old value.' from this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx

Comment: That's the key, not the hash.

Comment: @RolandShaw: yes but why then limit the key to one?  As I said in my question the only real reason I can see is just that MS wanted to simplify the interface or they have some clever hashing technique I'm not aware of that makes special use of the fact there is only one key?

Comment: C#'s Dictionary does not move objects around in memory. The CLR might do that as part of garbage collection, but the Dictionary class most  certainly does not, and it has no knowledge of the fact that its object may be moved around. So why would your faux-Dictionary move objects around? So you're trying to write a hash table which behaves like the .NET garbage collector? How does that make any sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [decompiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to see how the dictionary is implemented in mscorlib. It is too long to include, but here is a snippet:

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic { 

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Runtime.Serialization; 
using System.Security.Permissions; 

[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView<,>))] 
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]
[Serializable]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]
public class Dictionary<TKey,TValue>: IDictionary<TKey,TValue>, IDictionary, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback  { 

    private struct Entry { 
        public int hashCode;    // Lower 31 bits of hash code, -1 if unused 
        public int next;        // Index of next entry, -1 if last
        public TKey key;           // Key of entry 
        public TValue value;         // Value of entry
    }

    private int[] buckets; 
    private Entry[] entries;
    private int count; 
    private int version; 
    private int freeList;
    private int freeCount; 
    private IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer;
    private KeyCollection keys;
    private ValueCollection values;
    private Object _syncRoot; 

    // constants for serialization 
    private const String VersionName = "Version"; 
    private const String HashSizeName = "HashSize";  // Must save buckets.Length
    private const String KeyValuePairsName = "KeyValuePairs"; 
    private const String ComparerName = "Comparer";

    public Dictionary(): this(0, null) {}

    public Dictionary(int capacity): this(capacity, null) {}

    public Dictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer): this(0, comparer) {} 

    public Dictionary(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) { 
        if (capacity < 0) ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.capacity);
        if (capacity > 0) Initialize(capacity);
        this.comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    } 

    public Dictionary(IDictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary): this(dictionary, null) {} 

    public Dictionary(IDictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer):
        this(dictionary != null? dictionary.Count: 0, comparer) { 

        if( dictionary == null) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.dictionary);
        } 

        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> pair in dictionary) { 
            Add(pair.Key, pair.Value); 
        }
    } 

    protected Dictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        //We can't do anything with the keys and values until the entire graph has been deserialized
        //and we have a resonable estimate that GetHashCode is not going to fail.  For the time being, 
        //we'll just cache this.  The graph is not valid until OnDeserialization has been called.
        HashHelpers.SerializationInfoTable.Add(this, info); 
    } 

    public IEqualityComparer<TKey> Comparer { 
        get {
            return comparer;
        }
    } 

    public int Count { 
        get { return count - freeCount; } 
    }

    public KeyCollection Keys {
        get {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<KeyCollection>() != null);
            if (keys == null) keys = new KeyCollection(this); 
            return keys;
        } 
    } 

    ICollection<TKey> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Keys { 
        get {
            if (keys == null) keys = new KeyCollection(this);
            return keys;
        } 
    }

    IEnumerable<TKey> IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Keys { 
        get {
            if (keys == null) keys = new KeyCollection(this); 
            return keys;
        }
    }

    public ValueCollection Values {
        get { 
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ValueCollection>() != null); 
            if (values == null) values = new ValueCollection(this);
            return values; 
        }
    }

    ICollection<TValue> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values { 
        get {
            if (values == null) values = new ValueCollection(this); 
            return values; 
        }
    } 

    IEnumerable<TValue> IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values {
        get {
            if (values == null) values = new ValueCollection(this); 
            return values;
        } 
    } 

    public TValue this[TKey key] { 
        get {
            int i = FindEntry(key);
            if (i >= 0) return entries[i].value;
            ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException(); 
            return default(TValue);
        } 
        set { 
            Insert(key, value, false);
        } 
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) {
        Insert(key, value, true); 
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair) { 
        Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
    } 

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair) {
        int i = FindEntry(keyValuePair.Key);
        if( i >= 0 && EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(entries[i].value, keyValuePair.Value)) { 
            return true;
        } 
        return false; 
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair) {
        int i = FindEntry(keyValuePair.Key);
        if( i >= 0 && EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(entries[i].value, keyValuePair.Value)) {
            Remove(keyValuePair.Key); 
            return true;
        } 
        return false; 
    }

    public void Clear() {
        if (count > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < buckets.Length; i++) buckets[i] = -1;
            Array.Clear(entries, 0, count); 
            freeList = -1;
            count = 0; 
            freeCount = 0; 
            version++;
        } 
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) {
        return FindEntry(key) >= 0; 
    }

    public bool ContainsValue(TValue value) { 
        if (value == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
                if (entries[i].hashCode >= 0 && entries[i].value == null) return true;
            }
        }
        else { 
            EqualityComparer<TValue> c = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
                if (entries[i].hashCode >= 0 && c.Equals(entries[i].value, value)) return true; 
            }
        } 
        return false;
    }

    private void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>[] array, int index) { 
        if (array == null) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.array); 
        } 

        if (index < 0 || index > array.Length ) { 
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.index, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum);
        }

        if (array.Length - index < Count) { 
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Arg_ArrayPlusOffTooSmall);
        } 

        int count = this.count;
        Entry[] entries = this.entries; 
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (entries[i].hashCode >= 0) {
                array[index++] = new KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>(entries[i].key, entries[i].value);
            } 
        }
    } 

    public Enumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return new Enumerator(this, Enumerator.KeyValuePair); 
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator() {
        return new Enumerator(this, Enumerator.KeyValuePair); 
    }

    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated_required 
    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        if (info==null) { 
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.info);
        }
        info.AddValue(VersionName, version);

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
        info.AddValue(ComparerName, HashHelpers.GetEqualityComparerForSerialization(comparer), typeof(IEqualityComparer<TKey>)); 
#else 
        info.AddValue(ComparerName, comparer, typeof(IEqualityComparer<TKey>));
#endif 

        info.AddValue(HashSizeName, buckets == null ? 0 : buckets.Length); //This is the length of the bucket array.
        if( buckets != null) {
            KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[Count]; 
            CopyTo(array, 0);
            info.AddValue(KeyValuePairsName, array, typeof(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[])); 
        } 
    }

    private int FindEntry(TKey key) {
        if( key == null) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
        } 

        if (buckets != null) { 
            int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF; 
            for (int i = buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
                if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) return i; 
            }
        }
        return -1;
    } 

    private void Initialize(int capacity) { 
        int size = HashHelpers.GetPrime(capacity); 
        buckets = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < buckets.Length; i++) buckets[i] = -1; 
        entries = new Entry[size];
        freeList = -1;
    }

    private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add) {

        if( key == null ) { 
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
        } 

        if (buckets == null) Initialize(0);
        int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length; 

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING 
        int collisionCount = 0; 
#endif

        for (int i = buckets[targetBucket]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
            if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) {
                if (add) {
                    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Argument_AddingDuplicate); 
                }
                entries[i].value = value; 
                version++; 
                return;
            } 

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
            collisionCount++;
#endif 
        }
        int index; 
        if (freeCount > 0) { 
            index = freeList;
            freeList = entries[index].next; 
            freeCount--;
        }
        else {
            if (count == entries.Length) 
            {
                Resize(); 
                targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length; 
            }
            index = count; 
            count++;
        }

        entries[index].hashCode = hashCode; 
        entries[index].next = buckets[targetBucket];
        entries[index].key = key; 
        entries[index].value = value; 
        buckets[targetBucket] = index;
        version++; 

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
        if(collisionCount > HashHelpers.HashCollisionThreshold && HashHelpers.IsWellKnownEqualityComparer(comparer))
        { 
            comparer = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>) HashHelpers.GetRandomizedEqualityComparer(comparer);
            Resize(entries.Length, true); 
        } 
#endif

    }

    public virtual void OnDeserialization(Object sender) {
        SerializationInfo siInfo; 
        HashHelpers.SerializationInfoTable.TryGetValue(this, out siInfo);

        if (siInfo==null) { 
            // It might be necessary to call OnDeserialization from a container if the container object also implements
            // OnDeserialization. However, remoting will call OnDeserialization again. 
            // We can return immediately if this function is called twice.
            // Note we set remove the serialization info from the table at the end of this method.
            return;
        } 

        int realVersion = siInfo.GetInt32(VersionName); 
        int hashsize = siInfo.GetInt32(HashSizeName); 
        comparer   = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>)siInfo.GetValue(ComparerName, typeof(IEqualityComparer<TKey>));

        if( hashsize != 0) {
            buckets = new int[hashsize];
            for (int i = 0; i < buckets.Length; i++) buckets[i] = -1;
            entries = new Entry[hashsize]; 
            freeList = -1;

            KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array = (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]) 
                siInfo.GetValue(KeyValuePairsName, typeof(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]));

            if (array==null) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowSerializationException(ExceptionResource.Serialization_MissingKeys);
            }

            for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++) {
                if ( array[i].Key == null) { 
                    ThrowHelper.ThrowSerializationException(ExceptionResource.Serialization_NullKey); 
                }
                Insert(array[i].Key, array[i].Value, true); 
            }
        }
        else {
            buckets = null; 
        }

        version = realVersion; 
        HashHelpers.SerializationInfoTable.Remove(this);
    } 

    private void Resize() {
        Resize(HashHelpers.ExpandPrime(count), false);
    } 

    private void Resize(int newSize, bool forceNewHashCodes) { 
        Contract.Assert(newSize >= entries.Length); 
        int[] newBuckets = new int[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < newBuckets.Length; i++) newBuckets[i] = -1; 
        Entry[] newEntries = new Entry[newSize];
        Array.Copy(entries, 0, newEntries, 0, count);
        if(forceNewHashCodes) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
                if(newEntries[i].hashCode != -1) {
                    newEntries[i].hashCode = (comparer.GetHashCode(newEntries[i].key) & 0x7FFFFFFF); 
                } 
            }
        } 
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int bucket = newEntries[i].hashCode % newSize;
            newEntries[i].next = newBuckets[bucket];
            newBuckets[bucket] = i; 
        }
        buckets = newBuckets; 
        entries = newEntries; 
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key) {
        if(key == null) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
        } 

        if (buckets != null) { 
            int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF; 
            int bucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
            int last = -1; 
            for (int i = buckets[bucket]; i >= 0; last = i, i = entries[i].next) {
                if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) {
                    if (last < 0) {
                        buckets[bucket] = entries[i].next; 
                    }
                    else { 
                        entries[last].next = entries[i].next; 
                    }
                    entries[i].hashCode = -1; 
                    entries[i].next = freeList;
                    entries[i].key = default(TKey);
                    entries[i].value = default(TValue);
                    freeList = i; 
                    freeCount++;
                    version++; 
                    return true; 
                }
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) {
        int i = FindEntry(key); 
        if (i >= 0) { 
            value = entries[i].value;
            return true; 
        }
        value = default(TValue);
        return false;
    } 

    // This is a convenience method for the internal callers that were converted from using Hashtable. 
    // Many were combining key doesn't exist and key exists but null value (for non-value types) checks. 
    // This allows them to continue getting that behavior with minimal code delta. This is basically
    // TryGetValue without the out param 
    internal TValue GetValueOrDefault(TKey key) {
        int i = FindEntry(key);
        if (i >= 0) {
            return entries[i].value; 
        }
        return default(TValue); 
    } 

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>.IsReadOnly { 
        get { return false; }
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>[] array, int index) { 
        CopyTo(array, index);
    } 

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index) {
        if (array == null) { 
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.array);
        }

        if (array.Rank != 1) { 
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Arg_RankMultiDimNotSupported);
        } 

        if( array.GetLowerBound(0) != 0 ) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Arg_NonZeroLowerBound); 
        }

        if (index < 0 || index > array.Length) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.index, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum); 
        }

        if (array.Length - index < Count) { 
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Arg_ArrayPlusOffTooSmall);
        } 

        KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>[] pairs = array as KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>[];
        if (pairs != null) {
            CopyTo(pairs, index); 
        }
        else if( array is DictionaryEntry[]) { 
            DictionaryEntry[] dictEntryArray = array as DictionaryEntry[]; 
            Entry[] entries = this.entries;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
                if (entries[i].hashCode >= 0) {
                    dictEntryArray[index++] = new DictionaryEntry(entries[i].key, entries[i].value);
                }
            } 
        }
        else { 
            object[] objects = array as object[]; 
            if (objects == null) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Argument_InvalidArrayType); 
            }

            try {
                int count = this.count; 
                Entry[] entries = this.entries;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
                    if (entries[i].hashCode >= 0) { 
                        objects[index++] = new KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>(entries[i].key, entries[i].value);
                    } 
                }
            }
            catch(ArrayTypeMismatchException) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Argument_InvalidArrayType); 
            }
        } 
    } 

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { 
        return new Enumerator(this, Enumerator.KeyValuePair);
    }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized { 
        get { return false; }
    } 

    object ICollection.SyncRoot {
        get { 
            if( _syncRoot == null) {
                System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange<Object>(ref _syncRoot, new Object(), null);
            }
            return _syncRoot; 
        }
    } 

    bool IDictionary.IsFixedSize {
        get { return false; } 
    }

    bool IDictionary.IsReadOnly {
        get { return false; } 
    }
```

< The rest of the code ommited...>

Comment: That would be useful if the OP was simply trying to implement a hash table similar to the .NET Dictionary. But what he's actually trying to do is make a hash table *which also, in some unspecified way, acts like the CLR itself*'

Comment: Actually thats pretty much exactly what I wanted to see, thanks Ned. My question really just wanted to see if the C#'s virtual machine was doing some trick because of the wording in the documentation from this code its apparently not.  I'll certainly be using that decompiler from now on it seems to give pretty good results.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty similar to a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) though a std::map doesn't require you to add an entry to it first ... you can add by just using the map's entry

ie.

```
std::map< int, int > m;
m[78]++;
```

will create and increment the int value represented by the key "78" ...

Comment: I don't believe its implemented as a red black tree as the documentation says its insertion and removal are near O(1) time rather than a red black tree's O(log n) time.  See remarks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac.aspx